# how to capture returned values from php function parameter?

Tags: php

I am working with a wordpress plugin [Gravity Forms](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/).

The parameter `$value` `var_dump` result using `gform_field_validation` filter returns is  this...

```
string(4) "2434"
string(8) "Fantasma"
string(8) "fantasma"
string(13) "buzzlightyear"
array(1) {
  ["11.1"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(1) {
  ["15.1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
string(2) "10"
```

I'm trying to capture the first `string(4) "2434"` but I have no idea how to target this.

Is there some php magic that can allow me to target this first string?

I know it's utter filth but Gravity Forms has left me choice to get this integer using their [gform_field_validation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/) filter.

Any ideas or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that a `var_dump` of the returns?

Comment: Tell me about it... yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find that your output is the `gform_field_validation` being looped over all of the inputs.

If you are wanting to get the `$value` for a given field you will need to check the `$field` object to match what you are after such as this:

```
add_filter('gform_field_validation', function($result, $value, $form, $field) {
    if ($field->name == 'postcode') {
        return $value;
    }
});
```

This will then return the `$value` for the input named 'postcode' for example

Comment: Thank you that worked for me. I did understand how the `gform_field_validation` actually worked.